# Porque el return de esta funcion no retorna el numero de Registros de una tabla Formulada

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, funciones, datatables, plsql

Estoy aprendiendo funciones en ORACLE PL SQL y tengo un ejercicio en el cual me piden Hacer una función que retorne el número de Registros de la tabla VENDEDOR, lo que he intentado es hacer los siguientes:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countRegistros
RETURN NUMBER as cantidadRegistros 
variable := 0; 
CURSOR bc_cur IS

SELECT count(*) from vendedor
BEGIN

RETURN cantidadRegistros;
END;



VARIABLE Numero_Registros NUMBER;
EXECUTE :Numero_Registros := countRegistros();
PRINT Numero_Registros
```

pero a la hora de crear la función me aparece el siguiente error en el return

[image: error]

Si alguien me puede ayudar a terminar este ejericicio estaria agradecido gracias.

Comment: ¿Está bien puesto el `BEGIN`? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo hice así ,no se si te sirve.....espero que si

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countregistros RETURN NUMBER AS

```
cantidadregistros NUMBER;
```

BEGIN

```
SELECT

   count(employee_id)
    )
INTO cantidadregistros
FROM
    employees;

RETURN cantidadregistros;
```

END countregistros;

/

SELECT

```
 countregistros()
```

FROM
dual;

Comment: No pegues imágenes con código. Léete [answer] para aprender a elaborar buenas respuestas. Por favor, edita tu respuesta quitando esa imagen y pegando el código en su lugar, gracias.

Comment: Además, dale formato a la consulta, y explica brevemente cómo responde esto a la pregunta ("no sé si te sirve" no explica su funcionamiento). Como te han dicho, lee [answer].